# How do I update specific columns in Rooms database table on Android using target entity?

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I want to update only specific columns in my table in my Rooms database, and am using the target entity class by Android Rooms. However, when I execute the function, the value in the table does not get updated. Below are the activity class code, dao interface, my flight class, repository and view model code for this **update** function.

```
**Activity class**

flightViewModel.getAllFlights().observe(FlightDescriptionActivity.this, new Observer<List<Flight>>() {
          @Override
           public void onChanged(List<Flight> flights) {

           CateringTime cateringTime = new CateringTime("End",currentTime,currentTime,"These are catering comments");   
           flightViewModel.updateCateringData(cateringTime);
                  
                    }
                });

**FlightDao interface**

@Update(entity = Flight.class)
public void updateCateringData(CateringTime... cateringTimes);


**Flight Class** 

class CateringTime {

    //catering
     private String catering_button_status;
     private String catering_start_time;
     private String catering_end_time;
     private String catering_comments;

    //primary keys

    String flightNumber;
    String date;

    public CateringTime(String catering_button_status, String catering_start_time, String catering_end_time, String catering_comments) {
        this.catering_button_status = catering_button_status;
        this.catering_start_time = catering_start_time;
        this.catering_end_time = catering_end_time;
        this.catering_comments = catering_comments;
    }


**Flight repository class**

public void updateCateringData(CateringTime... cateringTimes){
        new UpdateCateringDataAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(cateringTimes);
    }



private static class UpdateCateringDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CateringTime, Void, Void> {

        private FlightDao flightDao;
        private UpdateCateringDataAsyncTask(FlightDao flightDao) {
            this.flightDao = flightDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(CateringTime... cateringTimes) {
            flightDao.updateCateringData(cateringTimes);
            return null;
        }
    }
}


**Flight View Model class** 


public void updateCateringData(CateringTime... cateringTimes) {
        
        repository.updateCateringData(cateringTimes);
    }
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this

```
@Query("UPDATE catering_time SET column = :column WHERE id = :id")
public void updateCateringColumn(String id, String column);
```

Comment: that is possible, but with target entity, the job becomes easier and faster